# Problems with nginx try_files setup

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to set up a project using django, gunicorn and nginx and I'm having trouble with the nginx configuration. More precisely when I use `try_files`.

If I use `if (!-f $request_filename) {...}` everything works fine but if use 
`try_files ...` Django generates the exception:

`Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'myproject_server'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.`

Once everything works using the `if ...` I assume that the other settings 
(gunicorn etc) are correct.

The configuration files I'm using are:

***/home/myproject/myproject/settings.py*** (django)

```
...
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [192.168.200.100, ]
...
```

***/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject (this one WORKS)***

```
upstream myproject_server {
    unix server:/home/myproject/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout = 0;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.200.100;
    root /home/myproject;
    location /media/ {}
    location /static/ {}
    location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $HTTP_HOST;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $REMOTE_ADDR;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://myproject_server;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

***/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject (this one DOES NOT WORK)***

```
upstream myproject_server {
    unix server: /home/myproject/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout = 0;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.200.100;
    root /home/myproject;
    location /media/ {}
    location /static/ {}
    location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $HTTP_HOST;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $REMOTE_ADDR;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        try_files $uri @myproject_backend;
    }
    location @myproject_backend {
        proxy_pass $scheme://myproject_server;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance any help.

**PS: English is not my native language so I apologize for the (many) errors.**

Comment: You should set `proxy_set_header`-s into last `location`

Comment: Hi Alexei Ten, now it works fine! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proxy_set_header` should be in the same location as `proxy_pass`.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @myproject_backend;
}

location @myproject_backend {
    proxy_set_header Host $HTTP_HOST;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $REMOTE_ADDR;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://myproject_server;
}
```